# Same style, different font color in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am using same style, however, it rendered different in chrome. It shows lighter. Is there a way to fore chrome render the style same with other browsers ?

```css
.text {
    color:#333435;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:arial;
    }
```

```html
<div class="text">Test text</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Basically? NO. Each browswer will choose to render fonts in it's own way. Without further details or a demo showing the issue, it's hard to offer any additional comment.

Comment: This is not showing a different colour exactly. It's because the top text is being [anti aliased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing), it therefore might look like a slightly different colour, but that's not what's actually happening.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this link](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/32276/why-does-my-hexadecimal-color-in-one-browser-render-differently-in-another-brows) for more information.

Colours aren't numbers. Each browser will use numbers to represent the colour but it will each display the colour slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I feel your pain. I come from print and it can be infuriating that you can't get everything perfect.

But, alas, you can't get everything perfect. If you want to know why here's a little article for you: [font rendering](http://szafranek.net/works/articles/font-smoothing-explained/)

Each browser will handle fonts a little differently and you kind of have to get right with it. When you have title or logo that needs to be exact consider converting it to an SVG.